# How to cast java interface to java object in scala

Tags: java, scala, casting

I am using a java object that returns a java interface and am a newbie with scala
I am trying to do the following:

```
val model = dao.getAccount(id)
```

model is an interface but I should be able to cast it as an object

but I know that in java I can cast this object like this:

```
model = (AccountModel) accountDAO.getAccount(id)
```

How do I do this in a scala app?

I tried this: `retVal.asInstanceOf(AccountModel)` but it doesn't seem to like that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there. It's `retVal.asInstanceOf[AccountModel]` (note the square brackets).

Comment: Thanks, thats it - doing java for over 10 years, trying to pick this up, not sure its worth it ;)

Comment: If you've been stuck in the Java monoculture for 10 years, you *desperately* need to do something else - for your sanity if nothing else ;-)

Comment: "Orangutans are skeptical / Of changes in their cages / And the zookeeper is very fond of rum." -- Paul Simon

Comment: @user197630 Scala is very regular. `AccountModel` is a type, and types are passed between square brackets. The same syntax that works for `asInstanceOf` works for every other method where you might want to pass the type parameter, and is reflected by the declaration of type parameters.

Comment: @user197630 If you still like Java after 10 years, it must be the Stockholm Syndrome...